# Separating invariant of a group action

Tags: group-theory

Let $G = (\mathbb{R},+)$ be a group, $M = \mathbb{R}^2$, 
$$\omega \colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \left(t, (x,y)\right) \mapsto(x+t,y-2t)$$
and
$$\iota \colon\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2, \quad (x,y) \mapsto y+2x.$$

Show that $\iota$ is a separating invariant.

Well, $G$ operates on $M$ since:

1) $\omega(1_G,(x,y)) = (x+0, y+2\cdot0) = (x,y)$

2) $g,h \in G: \omega((g+h),(x,y)) = (x+(g+h),y-2\dot(g+h)) = ((x+g)+h, (y-2g)-2h) = \omega(g,(x+h,y-2h)) = \omega(g,\omega(h,(x,y))$

$\iota$ is an invariant of $G$ because $\iota((x+t,y-2t)) = (y-2t)+2(x+t) = y-2t+2x+2t = y+2x = \iota((x,y)).$

Now I don't know exactly how to show that $\iota$ is an separating invariant. I have to show that if $\iota(m) = \iota(m')$ implies $Gm = Gm'$ with $m \in \mathbb{R}^2$. 
My approach is

$$x+t = x' \Rightarrow t = x' - x$$ and $$y-2t = y' \Rightarrow -2t = y' -y \Rightarrow -2(x'-x) = y' -y \Rightarrow 0 = (y'-y) + 2(x'-x).$$
Is that the right approach to show that the orbits $Gm$, $Gm'$ are equal with $m = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Note two misprints, first $\iota : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, and then you refer to $\iota$ as $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that $Gm = G m'$ if and only if $\iota(m) = \iota(m')$.

If $G m = G m'$, that is, $m' \in Gm$, then $m' = (x + t, y - 2 t)$ for some $t$, where $m = (x, y)$. Now $\iota(m') = y - 2 t + 2 (x + t) = y + 2 x = \iota(m)$.

Conversely, if $m = (x, y)$ and $m' = (u, v)$, suppose $\iota(m) = \iota(m')$. Then 
$$
v + 2 u = y + 2 x,
$$
that is
$$
v - y = 2(x - u).
$$
Set $u - x = t$ to get
$$
m' = (u, v) = (x + t, y - 2 t) \in G m. 
$$